# Improving performance of script

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos, rhel

I have been working on a script that can be used to automatically restart my Zabbix monitoring services in the event that they stop running. I have the script working just fine, but figured it could be improved.

```
#!/bin/bash
zabbix_server="service zabbix-server"
zabbix_agent="service zabbix-agent"
logfile=zabbix_auto_restart.log
logfilePath=/etc/scripts/zabbix/$logfile
zabbix_server_running=0
zabbix_agent_running=0

grep_agent (){
    local retval=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep zabbix_agentd | wc -l)
    echo $retval
}

grep_server (){
    local retval=$(ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep zabbix_server | wc -l)
    echo $retval
}

check_zabbix_agentd (){
    if (( $(grep_agent) == 0 ))
    then
       $zabbix_agent start
       echo `date` "$zabbix_agent was stopped... Restarting" >> $logfile
       echo "************************************************" >> $logfile

       #Send email to notify that the script ran
       echo "$(date) $zabbix_agent was restarted from zabbix_restart.sh" | mutt -s "Zabbix Auto-restart Script Just Ran" <user email>

    else
       let zabbix_agent_running=1
    fi
}

check_zabbix_server (){
    if (( $(grep_server) == 0 ))
    then
       $zabbix_server start
       echo `date` "$zabbix_server was stopped... Restarting" >> $logfile
       echo "************************************************" >> $logfile

       #Send email to notify that the script ran
       echo "$(date) $zabbix_server was restarted from zabbix_restart.sh" | mutt -s "Zabbix Auto-restart Script Just Ran" <user email>

    else
       let zabbix_server_running=1
    fi
}

main_loop (){
    until ((zabbix_server_running == 1 && zabbix_agent_running == 1));
    do
        check_zabbix_agentd
        check_zabbix_server
        sleep 1.5
    done
}

main_loop
```

Comment: Since your code is working "just fine," this question might be better posed on Code Review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is on code review lol. I figured posting on the Unix/Linux forum was a better idea. Given there are more people here who would be familiar with this. Code review people told me to "not re-invent the wheel".

Comment: As discussed in the [help center](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), cross-posting on multiple sites of the Stack Exchange network is [strongly discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-it-possible-to-post-questions-across-a-couple-of-the-sites-because-its-debata/64073#64073).

Comment: I did not get an answer on code review, which is why I came here. I think in the case of not receiving an answer it's a bit different.

Comment: For reference, the cross-posted version of this question is here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/94012/restart-services-automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're really doing wrong is duplicating your effort - basically every hardcoded occurrence of `_agent` or `_server` appears to be completely redundant.

For example, if this is being run on a linux system, you can completely drop the `grep_...()` functions, and consolidate both `check_...`s into a single entity which might work like:

```
email(){ 
    mutt -s "Zabbix Auto-restart Script Just Ran" \<user email\>
}
prlog(){ 
    date +"%x %X:%tservice $1${2+%n************************}"
}
chk_run()
    while  [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    do     if     ps -C zabbix_"$1"
           then   : "$(($1=1))"
           else   set zabbix_"$@"
                  service "$1" start || eval >&2 '
                  prlog   "$1 restart failed."  +; exit '"$?"
                  prlog   "$1 restarted."       +  >&2
                  prlog   "$1 restarted from $0." |email
           fi;    shift
    done
```

The key to that is you would just call `chk_run` with an argument list each member of which would indicate to it what it should be checking each iteration.

```
loop()
    until [ "$(($1&&$2))" -eq 1 ]
    do    chk_run "$@"
          sleep 2
    done  >/dev/null 2>>"$log"
agentd=0 server=0 loop agentd server
```

POSIXly the only thing that should need altering there is the `ps` command - because POSIX doesn't specify the `-C` switch. And so you could just change the `if` line to look like:

```
if    ps -eocomm= |
      grep -xqF zabbix_"$1"
```

Aside from `mutt`, `service`, and the `ps` optimization, it should all be standard command language.

At least one advantage to standard syntax is the `#!/bin/bash` hash-bang is completely unnecessary - there is no anchor here to some shell-specific extension, and so it should work pretty much exactly the same in all shells which strive for POSIX-compliance. That means that `#!/bin/dash` is a very simple *(and likely effective)* optimization in this case.

Of course, optimized or not, this script will almost always `sleep`.

I declined to define `$log` - mostly because there was nothing really to say about the way you defined it - that's all fine - but you might *want* to leave off defining it. If you can be sure of the script's calling environment, then it can make for a very simple means of passing in parameters. What I mean is, if the script is called `./script` and has already been made executable, then...

```
log=/dev/tty ./script
```

...will set the value for `$log` in the environment of `./script` when it is called.

I use `/dev/tty` as an example outfile because I think you should start with that while tweaking it to your satisfaction. If the code blocks here are put into `./script` and it is launched as described above, it will write in real-time to your terminal rather than some outfile - and so you can get a pretty clear idea exactly what will wind up in your real logfile when you eventually call it like:

```
log=./real/logfile ./script
```

Alternatively, as something like a hybrid behavior, you might change the script so that where it says `2>>"$log"` it says instead:

```
2>>"${log:-/hardcoded/default/path/to/logfile}"
```

...in which case the shell will only use the hardcoded value for `$log` if it is not already defined. This means that either of:

```
export log=/dev/tty; ./script
log=/dev/tty ./script
```

...will still write the logfile to the terminal, and either of...

```
log= ./script
unset log; ./script
```

...will write it to the hardcoded path, and...

```
./script
```

...will write either to the hardcoded path or to some other place depending on whether there is already a not-null value for `$log` exported to the current shell's environment.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  This is the kind of feedback I was looking for

Comment: @EvanBechtol - to get an idea of exactly what would wind up in the log and in real-time, run it at a shell prompt and set `log=/dev/tty` in its env. So, if the name of the script is `script` and it is located in the current directory, then you'd do: `log=/dev/tty ./script`. Anyway, I'm glad I could help you find what you were looking for.

Comment: @EvanBechtol - Oh, and you can also drop the `bash` bangline  - it will run far faster if the interpreter is `/bin/dash` - but it will run in any POSIX `sh`.